# Working with custom types in PostgreSQL and use them as arguments in functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Help me please , why i got the error function not exist ?

> > [2018-10-31 12:31:05] [42883] ERROR: function companytester(bigint, unknown, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
> >
> > Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION companyTester(founder Founder) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$

BEGIN

    RAISE NOTICE 'Founder id: %',founder.founder_id;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Founder FirstName: %',founder.firstname;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Founder LastName: %',founder.lastname;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Founder email: %',founder.email;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Founder password %',founder.f_password;

END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;



 SELECT companyTester(76565445354,'Maks','Burkov','Maks.Burkov88@gmail.com','+_@Maks88;

CREATE TYPE Founder AS (
  founder_id BIGINT,
  firstname VARCHAR(150),
  lastname VARCHAR(150),
  email VARCHAR(50),
  f_password VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing 5 parameters to the function, but it is declared to only accept one parameter (of type `founder`)

You need a [row constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) to create a proper instance of `founder` and thus passing only a single argument:

```
SELECT companyTester(
             (76565445354,'Maks','Burkov','Maks.Burkov88@gmail.com','+_@Maks88')::founder
       );
```

The expression `(76565445354,'Maks','Burkov','Maks.Burkov88@gmail.com','+_@Maks88')::founder`  is a single value

Alternatively you can use:

```
SELECT companyTester(row(76565445354,'Maks','Burkov','Maks.Burkov88@gmail.com','+_@Maks88'));
```